# Save textfield input as comma separated list in php

Tags: php, arrays, database, explode, implode

I would like to take a textfield input (job) and store it in my database with a comma separated list. This is what I've tried:

```
public function __saveNewJob($newJob,$jobscopeChosen) {
    $jobId = $this->__getScopeId($jobscopeChosen);
    $jobList = $this->__getJoblist($jobId);

    $jobList_comma = explode(",",array_filter($joblist));
    $jobList_array = array_push($jobList_comma,$newJob);
    $jobList_save = implode(",",$jobList_array);

    $query = "UPDATE xxxx SET jobs='".$jobList_save."' WHERE id='$jobId'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```

`$newJob` is the string from my textfield which I'd like to save.
`$jobscopeChosen` is a value from a select box.

The table in the database, named `jobs`, should be like `Designer, Producer, Administration` etc.

My idea was to get the comma separated list, explode it to an array, push the new value and implode it again to a string.

My database says `Array` in my table. I'm desperate. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: $jobList_comma is an array. Explode returns an array.

Comment: echo "$jobList_save" to confirm whether it is a string or array before store it in db.

Comment: It seems you're trying to use `explode()` on an array -- it requires a string, not an array. I'd suggest enabling error reporting to see what's really going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like using array_push when PHP has perfectly acceptable language structures built in like [].

You need to implode the correct array, so try this:

```
$jobList_comma = explode(",", array_filter($joblist));
$jobList_comma[] = $newJob;
$jobList_save = implode(",", $jobList_comma);
```

If this doesn't work for you, $joblist must be an array (required by explode) rather than a string, you should do a var_dump on it to check its type and contents, then you can work out what is wrong with it and how to fix it. If getJobList() returns an array from a database for example, you dont need to explode it, but you will need to filter out only the data you need and implode that for save.